# Acquiring employee information

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am curious to know if there is a faster, better, and more efficient way to accomplish this program that acquires employee information:

```
    <?php
session_start();
//require 'functions.php';
//require 'DB.php';
$employeeID = $_SESSION['employeeID'];
$clockIn = $_GET['clockIn'];
$clockOut = $_GET['clockOut'];
$timeToday = date("g:i a");
$dateToday = date("m/d/y");
$jobDescription = $_GET['jobDesc'];
$equipType = $_GET['equipTypeRan'];
$unitNumber = $_GET['unitNumber'];
$unitHours = $_GET['unitHours'];
if (isset($clockIn)) {

    echo "You clocked in at: " . $timeToday . " on " . $dateToday;

    try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=timecard', 'username', 'password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO timeRecords (employeeID, date, timeIn) VALUES (:employeeID, :dateToday, :timeIn)');

    $stmt->execute(array(':employeeID' => $_SESSION['employeeID'], ':dateToday' => $dateToday, ':timeIn' => $timeToday));

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;


} else if (isset($clockOut)) {

        try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=timecard', 'username', 'password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `timeRecords` SET `timeOut`= :timeOut WHERE `date`= :dateToday AND `employeeID`= :employeeID');

    $stmt->execute(array(':employeeID' => $_SESSION['employeeID'],':dateToday' => $dateToday, ':timeOut' => $timeToday));

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `timeIn` FROM `timeRecords` WHERE `date`= :dateToday AND `employeeID` = :employeeID');
    $stmt->execute(array(':employeeID' => $_SESSION['employeeID'], ':dateToday' => $dateToday));
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    $results = $stmt->fetch();
    $timeInDB = $results[0];

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $time_one = new DateTime($timeInDB);
    $time_two = new DateTime($timeToday);
    $difference = $time_one->diff($time_two);

    echo "You clocked in at: " . $timeInDB . "<br>";
    echo "You clocked out at: " . $timeToday . "<br>";

    echo $difference->format('Total working time %h hours %i minutes');

}else {

try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=timecard', 'username', 'password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timeRecords WHERE `timeOut` IS NULL AND `employeeID`= :employeeID AND `date`= :dateToday");

    $stmt->execute(array(':employeeID' => $employeeID, ':dateToday' => $dateToday));
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

if($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0){

    try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=timecard', 'username', 'password');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `timeRecords` SET `jobDescription`= :jobDescription, `equipType`= :equipType, `unitNumber`= :unitNumber, `unitHours`= :unitHours, 
                            `timeOut`= :timeOut WHERE `employeeID`= :employeeID AND `date`= :dateToday AND `timeOut` IS NULL');

    $stmt->execute(array(':employeeID' => $employeeID, ':timeOut' => $timeToday, ':dateToday' => $dateToday, ':jobDescription' => $jobDescription,
                         ':equipType' => $equipType, ':unitNumber' => $unitNumber, ':unitHours' => $unitHours));

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO timeRecords (employeeID, date, timeIn) VALUES (:employeeID, :dateToday, :timeIn)');
    $stmt ->execute(array(':employeeID' => $employeeID, ':dateToday'=> $dateToday, ':timeIn' => $timeToday));
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo "There was an update";
} else {
    echo "There was no Match";
}

    require 'summary.php';

}

?>
```

Comment: Why make the db connection so many times? Why not only once?

Comment: I guess there is not much to improve performance-wise (not in a noticeable order). However there's a lot of code duplication in there which could be reduced.

Comment: setting `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` will do exactly the same as wrapping your code in try catch. you can verify by removing them all together, a wrong query will still echo the same messages you echo in your catch part, but without the need of writing all those extra lines.

Answer (score 3):

Defining the same connection multiple times can be avoided, and also, putting everything in `try/catch` serves no purpose if the only thing you do in the catch is displaying the message which would be displayed anyway with the error reporting mode you set on the `$conn`

I also find that naming PDOStatements can help a bit for readability, instead of always using `$stmt`. Here it all happens in few lines, but sometimes, using a prepared statement far away in the code can be easier if they have significant names.

Doing this, I noticed your `clockIn` PDOStatement is done twice. Since the `if` prevents it from happening twice, it's OK, but perhaps you could find some use in preparing your PDOStatements outside of loops, then executing them in the loops.

```
<?php

session_start();
//require 'functions.php';
//require 'DB.php';
$employeeID = $_SESSION['employeeID'];
$clockIn = $_GET['clockIn'];
$clockOut = $_GET['clockOut'];
$timeToday = date("g:i a");
$dateToday = date("m/d/y");
$jobDescription = $_GET['jobDesc'];
$equipType = $_GET['equipTypeRan'];
$unitNumber = $_GET['unitNumber'];
$unitHours = $_GET['unitHours'];

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=timecard', 'username', 'password');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$putClockIn = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO timeRecords (employeeID, date, timeIn) VALUES (:employeeID, :dateToday, :timeIn)');

if (isset($clockIn)) {
    echo "You clocked in at: " . $timeToday . " on " . $dateToday;
    $putClockIn->execute(array(
        ':employeeID' => $_SESSION['employeeID'],
        ':dateToday' => $dateToday,
        ':timeIn' => $timeToday
    ));
    $conn = null;
} else {
    if (isset($clockOut)) {
        $putClockOut = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `timeRecords` SET `timeOut`= :timeOut WHERE `date`= :dateToday AND `employeeID`= :employeeID');
        $putClockOut->execute(array(
            ':employeeID' => $_SESSION['employeeID'],
            ':dateToday' => $dateToday,
            ':timeOut' => $timeToday
        ));
        $getTimeIn = $conn->prepare('SELECT `timeIn` FROM `timeRecords` WHERE `date`= :dateToday AND `employeeID` = :employeeID');
        $getTimeIn->execute(array(':employeeID' => $_SESSION['employeeID'], ':dateToday' => $dateToday));
        //$getTimeIn->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
        $results = $getTimeIn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH); // no need to set a mode for stmt if you ain't using it anywhere else, pass it directly in fetch()
        $timeInDB = $results[0];
        $time_one = new DateTime($timeInDB);
        $time_two = new DateTime($timeToday);
        $difference = $time_one->diff($time_two);
        echo "You clocked in at: " . $timeInDB . "<br>";
        echo "You clocked out at: " . $timeToday . "<br>";
        echo $difference->format('Total working time %h hours %i minutes');
    } else {
        $getCurrentSessions = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timeRecords WHERE `timeOut` IS NULL AND `employeeID`= :employeeID AND `date`= :dateToday");
        $getCurrentSessions->execute(array(':employeeID' => $employeeID, ':dateToday' => $dateToday));
        if ($getCurrentSessions->fetchColumn() > 0) {
            $closeSession = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `timeRecords` SET `jobDescription`= :jobDescription, `equipType`= :equipType, `unitNumber`= :unitNumber, `unitHours`= :unitHours, 
                                `timeOut`= :timeOut WHERE `employeeID`= :employeeID AND `date`= :dateToday AND `timeOut` IS NULL');
            $closeSession->execute(array(
                ':employeeID' => $employeeID,
                ':timeOut' => $timeToday,
                ':dateToday' => $dateToday,
                ':jobDescription' => $jobDescription,
                ':equipType' => $equipType,
                ':unitNumber' => $unitNumber,
                ':unitHours' => $unitHours
            ));
            $putClockIn->execute(array(
                ':employeeID' => $employeeID,
                ':dateToday' => $dateToday,
                ':timeIn' => $timeToday
            ));
            echo "There was an update";
        } else {
            echo "There was no Match";
        }
    }
}

require 'summary.php';
```